# All-in-one newsletter/digest sign-up, management, and delivery solution

Tags: web-apps, email, wordpress, newsletter

I am in search of a solution for a project that is strictly a newsletter/notification service, but with a bit of specific functionality.

On the front end, the user will sign up and then select a series of categories and subcategories they are interested in.

On the back end is mostly just data entry. Adding items to a database that are tagged with the aforementioned categories and subcategories.

The bit responsible for the emailing would send periodic emails based on the user's settings. So if they're signed up for instant notification, they would get an email immediately after an item is entered into the database. If they're set up for hourly or daily, then they would get emails with a list of items at those intervals.

---

I'm absolutely fine putting a few scripts together or buying something, or even using WordPress with some plugins. But, after a lot of searching, I have yet to find something that functions beyond a simple newsletter management.

Comment: I don't have personal experience with MailChimp (https://mailchimp.com), aside from being a user, but it sounds like it does a lot of what you're looking for. When I browsed https://inspiration.mailchimp.com/, there seemed to be fits, aside from the sub-categories. I couldn't find a match there. Doesn't mean there isn't, but I couldn't find it.

Comment: I would recommend Mailtrain https://mailtrain.org/. However I don't think it has a sign-up feature with categories.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you look at [Mautic](https://www.mautic.org) to use as part of your requirements, especially if you are going to put some scripts together.

- for period emails based on user's settings, see [here](https://www.mautic.org/docs/en/contacts/contact_preference_center.html)
- there are various wordpress plugins
- for categories, read [here](https://www.mautic.org/docs/en/categories/categories.html)
- its open source and you can self-host

Also look at the mautic forums for various tips/plugins

Comment: @s16 did you try this? Could you please tell us what you thought of it, in order to help others in future? Thank you